# Installing Ubuntu on many laptops

Tags: installation, preinstallation

At my company we are upgrading our hardware and I need to reinstall Ubuntu on ~15 laptops. Do you have any clues how to approach it? Do I need to sit in front of every machine and manually click through installation process? They are exactly the same machines and they need to be configured exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution:.
http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/unattended-ubuntu-installations

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The tutorial in the link was written for Ubuntu 10.04 which has already reached End of Life except for the Ubuntu Server and I seriously doubt that any of the 15 laptops mentioned in the question are going to be installed with Ubuntu Server.

Comment: In fairness to the tutorial, exactly the same should apply to current releases. Kickstart still exists.

Answer (score 0):

- You can install Ubuntu on one laptop.
- Configure it and install all software you need.
- Then make a bootable image of [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).
- Create an image of your new ubuntu on network filesystem (eg. nfs).
- Clone the image on all laptops.